# Can't edit or create Custom Search options via front end?

Tags: custom-search

I'm a little confused as to whether I should post likely bug reports here or on the forum since the top of the forum indicates that bug reports should still be there, but the Using CiviCRM boards are marked as deprecated...let me know if this is wrong!

On my Joomla install, confirmed on sandbox:

I go to Administer->System Settings->Option Groups then scrolling down to Custom Search and click Options.  I try to edit an existing option or add a new one.  When I click Save, I get the error "Value is a required field."

I assume the form should display the Value field as many other forms do.  Or if it's not meant to be user editable, it should be a hidden field and submit invisibly with the rest of the form.

I can work around this with direct sql queries as described at http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Custom-Search+Extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known reported bug, please check https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16254 and was fixed for 4.6.1

I would recommend upgrade to latest stable 4.6.2.